# How do I reset Ufraw to default settings in Windows?

Tags: software, gimp, windows, ufraw

The first time I played around with Ufraw / Gimp on my Windows machine, I hit "save" in Ufraw. Now, it opens every new photo with the odd warm settings I was playing with. How do I reset Ufraw  to just open the photo as it is?

I have uninstalled, restarted, reinstalled multiple times now.

Another thing I've tried is creating a new profile. It seems as though it is not tied to a user account but something system wide.

I was able to regenerate a new .ufrawrc file by saving new settings in there. If I rename / delete this file, the settings are still saved in the application somewhere. Here is the contents of my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UFRaw Version='7'>
  <WB>Manual WB</WB>
  <WBFineTuning>0</WBFineTuning>
  <Temperature>5187</Temperature>
  <Green>1.056</Green>
  <ChannelMultipliers>1.9245 1.0000 1.3705 1.0000</ChannelMultipliers>
<Exposure>0.333333</Exposure>
<BaseCameraCurve Current='yes'>
</BaseCameraCurve>
<LinearCurve Current='yes'>
</LinearCurve>
<MatrixInputProfile Current='yes'>Color matrix
</MatrixInputProfile>
<sRGBOutputProfile Current='yes'>sRGB
</sRGBOutputProfile>
<SystemDisplayProfile Current='yes'>System default
</SystemDisplayProfile>
<Make>NIKON</Make>
<Model>D3300</Model>
</UFRaw>
```

Maybe someone can give me the contents of their unedited file and I can try to copy/paste some of the values?

Comment: Alternatively, if you can recommend something better to view NEF's on windows, I'd be open to that.

Answer (score 2):

The config file of Ufraw is located in %USERPROFILE% and it is named .ufrawrc

You can delete or rename this file to reset your current settings

P.S. There is a dot as first symbol in filename

Comment: I've edited my question. I removed the file, and it kept the messed up settings. I've also created a new profile to test if this was this issue. Is there another place this file is stored?

Comment: @Jeff, have you stop the ufraw before remove the file? I test exactly this and w/o stopped ufraw i get saved values. But when I stop it, remove again the .ufrawrc and start again it show me the default values (i play with colour temperature)

Comment: Is ufraw a service? What do you mean stop?

Comment: No, this is just ordinary program. Better stop gimp and ufraw and then remove the file. And check if there is (eventually) some zombie process of ufraw

Comment: I am saying I have tried this, the file is no longer there.

Comment: Search for gimprc, there is possibility ufraw write in this file too. But just rename it (to have backup of your settings in gimp)

Answer (score 0):

The nUFRaw (https://sourceforge.net/projects/nufraw) is a new UFRaw version which has an handy button to reset all values. It's still in beta but you can try.